# What is the unit measure used to detect magnetic indentations in a hard drive?

Tags: single-word-requests, technology, measuring-units

As the title states, what is the unit measure used to detect magnetic indentations in a hard drive?

To clarify, what I mean by indentation is, what is measured to determine if a byte is a 1 or 0?

Comment: This question seems better suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jwodder, it depends on context. Where, hydroparadise, will you use this word? In a technical document? A novel?

Comment: @jwodder & OP: Surely, this should have been on a tech site, if a reliable answer is sought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually magnetic field is measured in *gauss*.
Others might use *tesla*, which is a unit much bigger than a gauss. 10000 gauss to a tesla, I think.
A milligauss would be a good unit to describe a small magnetic field, though I think on a disk it is likely to be much smaller than that.

Comment: However, I am pretty sure what is measured is the change in magnetic field, and the 1 or 0 is determined by when that changes.

Comment: You're right: it's the [change of] direction of field which is measured, and the field strength is of the order of milligauss. Lower-case for the names of units, incidentally.

Comment: Actually, what's being measured are _flux reversals_ -- the change from north pole to south, and vice versa. A flux reversal creates a voltage spike in the read/write head; these spikes, naturally, are measured in **volts**. (And, strictly speaking, aren't measured directly, but are used to generate a digital value.)

Comment: -1 Sounds more speculative/ presumptive than authentic. I understand, thought, since this Q. ought to have been on a tech site rather than on englishSE.

Answer (score 2):

**[Magnetic Hysteresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis#Magnetic_hysteresis)** is the measure used to determine electrical changes in the magnetic indentations on a hard drive disk.  Though the tesla or gauss *are* units of measure for magnetism, when taken alone they cannot properly measure nor set (write) the magnetized media on-disk.  The dynamics of hysteresis present a mechanism that can provide reliable basis for for measurement.

The magnetic indentations themselves are called [magnetic domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_memory).

These follow the same physical concept as [magnetic depressions](http://www.agu.org/pubs/crossref/2009/2009JA014283.shtml) in the atmosphere, or [in space](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997AdSpR..19..869C)